# Add Feature to Report an Answer as "Provably Incorrect"

Tags: feature-request

There is one thing that drives me absolutely crazy on this site more than any other: answers to algorithm questions that are provably incorrect.  Many times, these answers actually have up-votes, indicating that there are people searching for solutions that implemented incorrect algorithms in code.

I would love a new feature that allows users to flag an answer as provably false, so a moderator can remove it (or perhaps still show it but grey it out in an "incorrect" section) to help prevent future users from implementing poorly-formulated algorithms.  I feel that down-votes are simply inadequate for this purpose, as incorrect algorithms usually appear very easy to implement compared to the more involved, but correct algorithms next to them.

Comment: Here's an alternative thought:  if a user consciously decides to copy and paste a solution verbatim from Stack Overflow into their business application, what should the reasonable expectation be?  Voting helps guide the user on the right path; it doesn't necessarily give a rubber stamp to just copy and paste solutions.

Comment: You could consider these provably incorrect answers to be something akin to audits that Stack Overflow inflicts upon the programming world at large.

Comment: @Makoto I agree with you to a point... the second link I posted has an answer that is clearly incorrect, where a down-vote/comment seems adequate.  However, the answer in the second link has a very subtle bug, that most test cases would not reveal.  I could see someone implementing that logic, writing a test application that passes, and conclude that the logic is therefore correct (simply because their testing was inadequate).  In these cases, perhaps a harsher down-vote option could exist (for example, spend 10 rep to down-vote twice)?

Comment: You are singling out zero-net-score answers. They have no credibility to begin with.

Comment: "Clearly incorrect" is subjective and dependent on one's knowledge of the language and/or framework in question.  I'm not a C++ guru, so I neither agree nor disagree with your assertion.  I'm also not a fan of the harsher downvote; have you heard of [The Meta Effect™](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269349/1079354) in these parts?

Comment: @Air They were not zero-net-score until people reading this post went and voted on them for me.  Thank you to those people, but they were previously +2 and +1, respectively.

Comment: @Makoto Ah, I am guilty of initializing The Meta Effect as that post describes.  No, I had not heard of it as this is my first post on Meta.  When I said "clearly incorrect", I meant that there are very few test inputs that would result in a correct result (probably less than 10%).  In the other case the vast majority of test cases (probably over 90%) will pass.

Comment: @Makoto I removed the links from the question to put a stop to The Meta Effect you described.

Comment: Seems related: [someone is wrong](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/duty_calls.png)

Comment: @Makoto I disagree, an algorithm can be objectively incorrect given a rigorous specification of the desired output or behaviour

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Moderators don't have the time or breadth of subject matter expertise to possibly judge the correctness of answers being flagged.

You assume people wouldn't lie when flagging and / or use flags like this to destroy answers competing with their own. Unfortunately, this happens nearly every day. If we were to trust all such flags, many great answers would be destroyed regularly.

This would also place the final measure of what is and is not a correct answer in the hands of a dozen or so people. That severely undermines the community, and would reduce the trust in the voting system.

There's a very good reason why one of our standard flag decline reasons reads:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

Comment: Fair enough; I guess it is their own fault for not performing due diligence in ensuring an answer is correct before accepting it as such.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 8):

This feature already exists.  Look for the link titled "add a comment".

Other experts who read the answer will see your explanation why it is wrong, and join you in downvoting.  They will also upvote your comment, ensuring that it always appears with the answer.  Once the score is negative enough, it automatically becomes grey, and experts will have the additional option to vote to delete it.

If that isn't happening, perhaps your proof is either itself faulty, or just explained poorly.

Comment: The only thing that I will say is wrong with this is your statement "join you in downvoting".  My rep isn't high enough to down-vote, so when I realize something is wrong, I have no way to flag such a situation (other than comments, which are frequently hidden and/or ignored).  I am very frustrated that giving sound, correct answers here doesn't get me to the point where I can actually fully utilize the site.

Comment: @JeffG:  You need literally one more upvote to gain that privilege.  Then you can use it up to twice without any more upvotes before you fall below the threshold again.  The best way you can identify the situation is still either comments or downvotes.  The excellent answer by Brad Larson is just as effective; moderators simply can't be subject matter experts in all language at all times.  I can understand and appreciate that there are people that will get it wrong, but there are only the two tools to point out the error of their ways.  And, I dare say that they are *effective* at that.

Comment: @JeffG: You can also utilize the chatrooms, which will often accelerate the process.

Comment: @Ben I didn't even realize there were chat rooms.  Thanks for the advice.