# Highly-upvoted incorrect answers on questions are harmful

Tags: discussion, feature-request

[I'm well aware this ground has been trodden before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255198/how-to-handle-historical-highly-upvoted-but-completely-incorrect-answers), but the ground has changed a lot in half a decade. Without further ado, the question.:

[What is the difference between String and string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string-in-c)

[The only correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27965515/70345) is **25th** in terms of votes; there is pretty much zero chance of it ever being seen, unless it somehow manages to accumulate over a **hundred times** as many upvotes as the accepted answer. There's no way to sort answers by newest, either; altering the accepted answer to be correct could be considered vandalism, and does a disservice to the user who posted the actually correct answer. Creating a new, canonical question and answer with the correct information, then flagging the original as a dupe of the original, is problematic because again credit is not given where due, and of course flagging is up to the whims of the community.

**Questions with incorrect accepted answers are not helpful or useful on a QA site that intends to be high-quality; in fact, they are actively harmful.** Moderators need a way to fix issues like these, and my suggestion is the following:

1. If the question is not a community wiki question, convert it to community wiki to preserve and freeze rep allocation until that point.
2. Change the accepted answer to the different, correct answer on that question.

Additionally, ordinary users need a new flag to raise this issue for mod attention. This type of flag must only be handled by mods who have experience in the technology(ies) involved.

Comment: What I gather from the answer you point out in that thread is the other answers are wrong only because someone could write code to override the default meaning of what people would expect it it to return. In this case I would not call the other answers wrong but it be worth mentioning that the expected default behavior can be changed.

Comment: Oh, I'm sure most C# programmers will survive with their mental model in tact.  It is often necessary to provide an abstraction when the Unvarnished Truth is entirely too convoluted.  You can't expect everybody to understand how a compiler works.  Or take the time to explain what a "keyword" really means, nobody did.  I tried to point out before that int won't be a 32-bit variable forever, people got quite upset over that.  Mental model violations hurt.

Comment: @JoeW An answer that says, "there is no difference", when there are in fact a bunch of differences, is in fact wrong.  (Jeppe's answer doesn't even provide an exhaustive list, just a few examples of differences.)

Comment: Your idea is to switch the burden of answer quality from the community to the moderator since they will control which answers to keep on a question. I prefer the current model where community voting drives the site rather than select users. If there is an incorrect answer you could always leave a comment explaining your viewpoint so when others view the answer they can see why you feel its wrong.

Comment: *"but the ground has changed a lot in half a decade"* - in what way? Especially everything that passes through in this meta post, everything is exactly as it was and likely will still be exactly as it is 5 years from now.

Comment: "The only correct answer is 25th in terms of votes" It seems like most of the answers, including the accepted answer, are correct in identifying that `string` means `System.String`. How is the one you linked to "the only correct answer"? I only see 3 or 4 answers on the first page that actually say there is no difference. I do agree, however, that most of the answers are duplicates and can safely be deleted. If you flag such answers for mod attention and specify how they don't provide any new information over the top 2 or 3 answers, you'll likely get good traction (and reference this meta)

Comment: @Servy I do agree there are differences but in this case it is something that a user would have to go out of their way to cause and from my experience it is unlikely that people override key functions like this.  So in most cases the differences are not something that a user will ever encounter. I guess my question is where do we decide that an answer is wrong because the system allows a user to override things to be the opposite from the default.

Comment: @TylerH `string` is an alias for `global::System.String`.  Several answers say that, and use that as their justification for saying that `string` and `String` are the same thing.  But while the first sentence is true, the *consequences* of that alias existing result in *lots* of differences between `string` and `String`.  It's that statement about the differences that result from that alias existing, that make the answers wrong.

Comment: @JoeW And an answer that said, "There are differences but they're unlikely to come up so don't worry about it." could be a perfectly fine answer (it's at least not wrong; whether you think describing the differences in detail is useful is of course a judgement call).  But just because differences don't come up in lots of situations doesn't mean there aren't any.  And telling people there aren't any just makes it all the more confusing when people *do* end up in those situations.

Comment: @Servy: In the time spent making all of these comments, you (or anyone else) could easily have edited the primary answer to add information about the distinction between an alias and the name. It's a community-wiki answer, so that level of editing is not unreasonable.

Comment: I think I have the solution to this problem. Hear me out, and don't call me crazy, but how about editing the answer to mention the specific exception?

Comment: To me it seems like the problem is, that the first one to ask a question is given disproportional power over selecting the correct answer. The first one can accept an (any) answer. Subsequent SO users (who do their research before asking) with the same question will find the existing question, get some answer and don't re-ask. So their demand is similar to the first one who asked (I have a question, I get an answer), but their voting power is limited to an upvote. If the community is supposed to find the best answer, maybe there's need to reduce the impact of accepting an answer.

Comment: @grek40 that is only if like many other people you read "accepted answer" and morph that into "correct answer". Accepted != correct.

Comment: @Gimby its more that the accepted answer is most likely to attract votes and thus, if to many people assume the answer to be correct (like you say), it can be upvoted for no good reason. Ofcourse I scroll down the answers if I feel like there's something wrong, but the system can still be improved as long as "top answer" doesn't equal "correct answer"

Comment: Isn't the basic problem that an answer is more likely to be up voted by someone who doesn't know / care about the more fine grained details of the langue (e.g. a beginner looking for a quick answer) than down voted by someone who knows / cares about details (e.g. a senior programmer with time to sort out the specifics)?

Comment: ...and isn't this the general problem of social media, that experience of all the participants is "not on the top level" and that the time time they have available (or are willing to spend) to really, really understand things is limited?

Comment: ...actually the social media is worse, people influence each other ( corelated vs. independent voting) For independent voting, the crowd of idiots can actually work better than the experts  (https://www.npr.org/sections/money/2015/08/07/429720443/17-205-people-guessed-the-weight-of-a-cow-heres-how-they-did) Not to mention most in stackoverflow are in some way experts. But no answer and no model is perfect - still some of them are useful... and at times there can be multiple  correct answers / models, even mutually exclusive. (Imho, this applies to answers and models, not facts though.)

Comment: @Braiam I've never been comfortable with editing someone else's answer into a completely different one, perhaps because other sites in the SE network frown upon such things and actively reject such edits.

Comment: Please provide examples of other sites. SO os the only one I've seen it happen. Heck, I've seen a case where since the author didn't accept the better version, the community just posted that version and buried the unedited one in down votes.

Comment: [This may be relevant to your interests.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314426/621962)

Comment: Just a note that this is actively being talked about internally too. We've _almost_ implemented a system to deprecate old answers that were once great, but now pretty .. not great ... several times and we just need to bite the bullet and get it done. I'll put an answer more properly soon, I just need to see how this has solidified on our side before I tease out too many possibilities (there are a few ways we can go, all of them have potential drawbacks).

Comment: @TimPost why implement something new, when you already implemented the solution? Just make people *edit more*. Edit, and edit and edit until [this graph doesn't look bad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314426/792066).

Comment: On the plus side, this answer is up a few places from 25th now.

Comment: The accepted answer (which was written years before the answer you claim is the first correct answer) is not wrong. In fact, it repeats the first line of the Microsoft documentation but expands `String` to `System.String`. The only thing missing from it is that it omits a discussion of the fact that `String` does not necessarily refer to `System.String`. Determining that a popular answer is wrong, is not as straight forward as you seem to think.

Comment: Perhaps it's time for silver/gold tag badge holders to be able to mark answers as deprecated? Requiring 2 or 3 people to vote too?

Comment: @JeremyP None of the answers are wrong, but some of them are more correct and useful than others.

Comment: I suggest we forget  this specific question or on the problem where there are wrong answer. Because some people obviously interpret the fact that ``String s = "hello world";" could be a non compiling statement where people like me does, which me the specific case of the "right 25th answer" is plainly wrong. While I agree that sometimes some high-upvoted answers are bad. I really disagree with that specifc case. If you want we could even edit OP's question where we add that we consider that both statement compiled successfully.

Comment: The Java equivalent for the linked "better" C# answer would be saying that `String` "can be anything" because you _could_ have an `import com.example.String` somewhere. And, **while it is technically true, it is far from a useful answer for most users asking "What is String in Java?"**. My course of action here would be to leave a comment on, or maybe edit, the accepted answer to leave a note about checking our namespace to make sure that `String` is what we expect it to be.

Comment: @Walfrat I was only pointing out that the accepted answer was not wrong to show that it is not necessarily cut and dried that an answer you think is wrong is actually wrong. The answer given as correct in the question was certainly a more complete answer and a better answer, but it wasn't posted until many years later, hence the problem of it being buried.

Comment: And as I said, I consider the top answer to be better than the one you're talking taking into account the OP question, since the said question wasn't asking why it wasn't compiling. However my main point is that we should either focus on the specific problem with that question, or focus on the point the title of this post point without discuss the choice of the choosen question, which is more debatable than some other on the network.

Comment: @walen No, a better Java equivalent example would be question asking, "is it possible for `String` to be anything other than `java.lang.String` and someone posting an answer saying, "No" (which is both demonstrably wrong, and very much unhelpful).  This question was not "what is a string in C#" to which everyone could have assumed the language's implementation, not some custom implementation.

Comment: @TimPost It's worth noting that this example (and the class of situations this meta question appears to be asking about) involves answers that have always been bad, even from the start, and have simply been upvoted despite problems *they've always had*.  This isn't about techniques that were the best with the tools available at the time, but to which better solutions now exist.

Answer (score 45):

The problem is you can't just assume that moderators are going to be adequately knowledgeable about the subject to judge when the existing answers are wrong, and what the right answers are.  The whole point of moderators is that they're not subject matter experts, they're SO experts.  They're knowledgeable about how the site works, and are able to help resolve disputes.  Those are very different skillsets than explaining nuanced compiler semantics in C# in a way that's both correct and understandable.

So yes, it sucks when the community's voting is wrong.  But it's just as problematic to trust in a moderator that's not adequately knowledgeable about a subject matter to just pick an answer, because when they're wrong there's even *less* agency for dealing with the problem.

Comment: Maybe language tag gold badgers could be given an extra priviledge to vote for deletion of incorrect answers, if a number of them agrees the answer could be deleted despite the high number of upvotes.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I actually had a similar idea, but decided not to mention it because this seems like it's moving some moderator power to gold badgers - I have zero problems with this, but I've got the impression that SO is extremely reluctant to allow mod privileges to "trickle down" to ordinary users.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have posted an answer that largely aligns with your comment.

Comment: Gold badge owners already have the power of Mjölnir to insta-dupe-close any question within their tag-dominions, overriding the Close queue. If there was a new *"Outdated"* queue where you could flag answers as outdated and pick the up-to-date answer, so a "This answer has a more up-to-date version here" notice would show in the outdated answer; and gold badge owners could insta-mark said answers as outdated overriding this new queue, it would be exactly the same mechanism we have now for dupes.

Answer (score 12):

The involvement of moderators in determining correct answers has been discussed in at least these two previous Meta questions:

- ["Why are we supposed to let incorrect answers stick around?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287603/why-are-we-supposed-to-let-incorrect-answers-stick-around)
- ["Add Feature to Report an Answer as 'Provably Incorrect'"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288148/add-feature-to-report-an-answer-as-provably-incorrect)

In both cases, I pointed out that this largely comes down to a matter of who to trust. I'll quote from one of my answers there:

> Using flags to get moderators to delete incorrect answers is
>   problematic for several reasons. First, it requires moderators to be
>   subject matter experts in the field to make a judgment like that. We
>   can't possibly have enough moderators to cover every technology on
>   this site.
>
> Blindly trusting flaggers would be a terrible idea, based on the
>   number of flags people falsely cast on competing answers in an attempt
>   to fool us into destroying them. Lots of people abuse flags to attack
>   anything they disagree with, or to try to benefit themselves. This is
>   why we can be more skeptical about some of these.
>
> Beyond that, do you really want to have a small cabal of people decide
>   what's correct and what's not? I certainly don't, and would much
>   rather let the community judge correctness via votes.

What you're proposing is different from flagging for deletion of wrong answers, but it suffers from the same issues of trust. Moderators cannot be subject matter experts on every topic on the site, and we would get all kinds of false flags to demand we switch accepted answers. How could we decide who was right and wrong? Would you want a small group of people to be the final arbiters of what's correct?

That's not to say that there aren't things that could be done to improve the situation. [Not pinning the accepted answer at the top of the post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top/326119#326119) is something I'll continue to push for, because it gives the asker a disproportionate influence on what is presented as being correct. I'm certain there are other ways to combat correct answers being buried behind older ones with more votes, but it's a tough problem.

Comment: I think I have the solution to this problem. Hear me out, and don't call me crazy, but how about editing the answer to mention the specific exception?

Comment: @Braiam - Do you trust the person making the edits to not render the answer incorrect or to introduce incorrect information? In this specific example, maybe, but in the general case it's still a tough call.

Comment: I trust that there are enough users that are following the tag that will check it out and correct anything wrong. The same way I trust you not to go bananas, because there are others to supervise what you do. There's always watchers to the watchmen.

Comment: @Braiam editing will only add more information when there actually is already. There is always a right answer below a question, can we make the accepted answer to say "refer to that answer"? A feature request will be to add an official yellow banner.

Comment: @window.document there was a time, where someone somewhere imagined that Stack Overflow [would be a wiki first](https://blog.codinghorror.com/what-does-stack-overflow-want-to-be-when-it-grows-up/#stackoverflowisawikifirst), which meant to communicate "let's **collaboratively** build an artifact that will benefit future coders". How can there be collaboration without working over someone work?

Comment: @Braiam I agree but editing the accepted answers to include the same information which is already there in the form of an answer below will be redundant. SO is still a wiki but a different type of wiki which includes problems and their answers in a Q&A format.

Comment: @Braiam you have more faith than me. Its a question almost 11 years old, I can scarcely believe that an edit to one of the answers is going to be see much scrutiny even if the question is hoisted back into the active questions for a brief moment. You have to really be out looking for the change.

Comment: @Gimby Well, I don't. The system does, and I have faith *in the system*.

Answer (score 8):

> I think I have the solution to this problem. Hear me out, and don't call me crazy, but how about editing the answer to mention the specific exception? – Braiam

The [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) community has been known to do this a little. R community ([r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r)) has several large errors that the reoccur in different flavors.
In fact, community has to often edit answers to questions pertaining to every 3-6 months. (Before I go on, I would like someone who is a major contributor to [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) or a moderator to elaborate on this topic if they can as I am not an expert in the reasons of why the above statement is true).

Take for example installing the two major educational packages of R *swirl* and *rattle*, that every beginner in R should use(*).  If you have a Mac, then the problem is that rattle is one of the about 100 or so libraries that constantly fails to install. And so a new solution has to be found to this problem every time Mac or R updates. Today, you more or less have to hack your Mac to get R to work properly.

Just search this: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=RGTK2+%5Br%5D+install  or rattle and Macs and you will see what I mean. In fact, if you go deeper you will find that many of the popular answers do not contain the word "xcode" at all. Many have even been updated:

- https://yihui.name/en/2018/07/cranextra-macos/
- https://rattle.togaware.com/rattle-install-mac.html

Many times though people just make new questions for this particular question. In the Stack Overflow link above there are a lot of duplicate questions, but you should also notice that there are intentionally few (this is a duplicate thread warnings).

So I think editing the answer has some applications, but it needs to be done more often, which means more volunteers, which means... well you get the idea.

(*)Along with a bunch of other packages, but this is not a post about learning R.

Comment: Thanks, Heretic Monkey and the other people who edited this.  I really appreciated it.

Answer (score 6):

I think we've all come across incorrect accepted and wildly upvoted answers at some point in our journey.

With its amazing volume of knowledge and experts, Stackoverflow can now afford to cast its attention to cleaning up spills on aisle 9.  Yes, we have watchers and watcher-watchers, but not everything gets caught.

I also agree with others that possessing a diamond is not, by itself, a qualifier to judge correctness of content.

The good news is: we already have a mechanism by which the public can assess content and intercept content that is not beneficial to the community -- Review Queues.

For the best chance at fairness which is delivered by a **high** volume of reasonably qualified assessors, let's add another category to the Moderation Queues that is purely for "gold badgers".

Every time you earn a new gold badge, that new tag qualifies you to review flagged answers with that tag, then vote to Delete, Keep, Edit, or Skip.

Definitely Edit if the answer just needs a little TLC.

A Delete vote MUST be cast with a justification.  The justifications will be finite.  Just like voting to close, you need to say why for transparency.

For example, you might vote to remove because an edit can not resuscitate the post and:

- the answer does not provide the expected result which is 100% clear in the question
- the answer endorses practices with SEVERE security ramifications which will be detrimental to unknowing researchers
- the answer says that the task is "impossible" and a possible solution is/can be provided

You vote to Keep if:

- The answer provides reasonable accuracy within the scope of the posted question.  In other words, it contains enough correctness to stay (again perhaps edit it if slightly undercooked).  The goal is to bring SO up, not bring posters down.

If you are worried that purists/extremists will buzzsaw through content and do harm, then add safeguards.  Instead of getting a verdict from a handful of voters, make a decision only after there is an overwhelming majority of support one way or the other from the gold badgers -- a determination by a margin of 50 votes (whatever number or percentage). Limit the number of votes you can cast in a time period - like everything else here.

If you are worried that this will scare off new users, then only permit the flagging of answers which are *n* years or older (e.g. 5).

Or make flagging non-negative answers for deletion cost a reimbursable (if/when the delete was approved) 10 rep points.  I know I would cop the -10 if I was confident that I was flagging appropriately.

Even after all that, if you can't trust the community, pass the majority verdict on to moderators for final approval.

Basically, meh answers should be safe from expulsion - we don't want this to be abused.  Just keep building safeguards until you can be happy.

---

Inspired by this topic which focusses on bad content, let's consider rewarding the good content in a similar fashion...

If a question with one or more answers is a good, clear question (shouldn't be closed for any reason) but has been abandoned because the OP:

1. has been de-registered (an ownerless question) or
2. has not logged in for *n* years (let's say 5)

then let's investigate if there is a green tick worthy answer and dignify contributors for their effort.

By casting our attention to the poisoned and abandoned pages here, we stand to make real positive change where previously people have merely shrugged their shoulders and said "there's nothing I can do to fix these kinds of messes".

Finally, rather than scrutinizing the half-considered context and rules that I have jotted down, please help to refine these suggestions for the Review Queues.  There will be concerns about gamification, collusion, and fringe cases, but those issues are already threats with existing features here, so don't throw the baby out with the bath water.  This might even rekindle the SO love from veterans who have become bored from years of doing the same tasks here.   Be bold enough to try to make the site even better than it already is.  Talk it out!

Answer (score 1):

I figure that the only real solution to this problem would be one that engages the community as opposed to diamond moderators.

The solution that I've pictured is somewhat similar to what the tag dashboard and discussion features of the defunct Documentation looked like. A place where those knowledgeable in a tag can discuss specific questions and answers as well as more general tag moderation policies with others who are knowledgeable in that technology. Something like a meta, but for each tag specific to the tag being discussed.

This wouldn't give anyone any more authority to delete content, but it would allow users to bring more *knowledgeable* attention to problems that they identify, and allow for discussion around what the ideal solutions to these problems might be.

I realize that this is very naive and would require much more thought before any kind of consideration could take place, but it seems like the most ideal solution in my eyes.

Just daydreaming here.

Comment: Sounds like something that could be handled by a meta post that starts a chat room for discussion on the topic, that ultimately results in either a diamond mod performing an action or nothing.

Comment: @KevinB The point is that the meta audience is not necessarily representative of any given tag's expert pool. The vast majority of tag experts rarely visit meta if at all. If this was put in front of tag experts every time they visit the site then it would get a lot more focused attention from those who have the most invested in the given tag. Realistically putting stuff on meta has the same problems as mod-flagging does.

Comment: Yes, however that's solvable. The point is to get people involved in that tag involved in the discussion. Whether that means promoting that discussion on meta, or presenting it to people who follow the tag via a side widget, is logistics.

Comment: @KevinB So you'd rather a mass of overly specific stuff that generally isn't relevant to anyone except those experienced in the tag at hand spread about meta and a bunch of chat rooms that aren't searchable, as opposed to an interface that organized everything so that the information and discussions relevant to a group of people are displayed to those people and not to people who have no interest in the topics being discussed? That sounds helpful.

Comment: No, not at all. What i'm proposing is getting the people who should be involved in it involved in it. The post has to exist somewhere, and meta is the only appropriate place for that.

Comment: @KevinB Did you miss the part of my post where I propose a new appropriate place for that? Like... my whole post? The entire point of my post being that Meta is not an adequate solution to the problem for a variety of reason, but the main reason being that the Meta user base is not representative of any given tag's expert pool. I'd rather not try to get every tag expert on meta discussing every problem with every question. I think that would be a really bad idea. I think a much better idea would be to have a tag dashboard and discussions for each tag, _not on meta_.

Comment: So, you want meta discussions spread out among thousands of tags? hidden in their wiki's?

Comment: @KevinB No, I want tag specific discussion displayed prominently on tag-specific dashboards readily available for perusal by those knowledgeable in the given tag. Obviously general meta discussions would still belong on meta, but discussions specific to a given tag that would be of no interest to anyone but those knowledgeable in the given tag would have a home where people who care could see them.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone mentioned it may be time to consider the Wilson confidence score interval ?
c.f. the famous story by Evan Miller http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html

I'm not saying go with exactly the reddit score, but thinking mathematically about how to show fairness with regard to votes through time integration. (time passing multiplies bias)

Randomization is done for elections here so it's not unheard of. game theory is a thing. Following yellow vest riots a lot of discussion has popped about democracy, voting systems: condorcet, candidate rankings etc. and oracle effects (maybe related https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wisdom_of_the_crowd ?)
Some study showed that individually nobody knew the melting point of aluminium accurately, but the gaussian mean pinpointed it very accurately. This should be proof that with correct game theory, the real best answer has a way to bubble up and win.

Now it's a question of adjusting the maths so that it happens.

Answer (score -4):

For some reason, OP (and a lot of answerers and commenters too) assume that users should upvote correct answers and downvote incorrect ones.

However, if you happen to hover over the upvote button, the tooltip is

> This answer is useful.

One could argue that an answer may be technically incorrect, or may ignore advanced considerations for the sake of simplicity, and still provide adequate and useful insight on the question. Of course, more often than not, an answer being incorrect is harmful to its usefulness.

As far as the C# question you mention is concerned, the most-upvoted answer is suitable for most cases. A nested class named `String` is (imho) a very specific edge case, and the answer that mentions it is useful too, but far less concise.

Comment: Agree, it is clear for me than OP is asking for the structural difference between System.String and string. I don't think OP really cared about the namespace trap, It is worth being told, but doesn't make the others answers wrong IMO. So I have upvoted the already high upvoted answers.